# MySQL Trigger with custom IF Statement with insert

Tags: mysql, sql

I've tried to create trigger. I want to insert a new row in another table using my trigger.

```
Tabel1
name - varchar(50)
type - tinyint(1)
permission - varchar(200)

Tabel2
username - varchar(32)
playtime - int(11)
```

And here is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trusted` AFTER UPDATE ON `playTime` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (SELECT playtime FROM playTime WHERE username = username ) >= 84600
THEN INSERT INTO plugs.permissions(`name`, `type`, `permission`) VALUES (`username`, 1 ,`lokiblocker.list.allow.trusted`);
END IF; 
END
```

I want to insert new row into `Tabel1`, if row '`playtime`' in `Table2` equals 84600

What shall I do?

Comment: what are exactly the name of the tables? is playTime in the first line of the trigger the name of 2nd table?

Comment: I'm surprised the question is put on hold. It's certainly not perfect but it's clear minus minor details. If one is strict with SSCCE guidelines (not rules of law) then it would leave out a lot of people which do not have yet a good grasp of the topic at hand, as is clearly the case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trigger test should be:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `trusted` AFTER UPDATE ON `playTime` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF new.playtime >= 84600 THEN
   INSERT INTO plugs.permissions(`name`, `type`, `permission`) 
   VALUES (new.username, 1 ,"lokiblocker.list.allow.trusted");
END IF;
END $$
```

Comment: `CREATE TRIGGER trusted AFTER UPDATE ON playTime FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF new.playtime >= 84600 THEN
   INSERT INTO plugs.permissions(name, type, permission) 
   VALUES (new.username, 1 ,"lokiblocker.list.allow.trusted");
END IF;
END` 
Doesn't work. 
`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5 `

Comment: I think you forgot the delimiter statement